# Query Firebase and get Key

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query firebase and if the record exists I want to unique key but cannot seem to get it. My filter works fine but I don't know what the object property names are and can't seem to find anything on firebase that helps. The .key() always returns an error. Here is what my object looks like when I return it

```js
GET /js/init.js 200 5.048 ms - 207
GET /img/logo.png 200 2.376 ms - 2793
{ '-KP8qXgQRaeClqzKX1Lo': { email: 'bdole@gmail.com' } }
GET /sent 200 7.923 ms - 8110
```

Here is my code

```js
    firebase.database().ref('/customers').orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    },function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
```

I need that key because if it exists I need to use that for the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    firebase.database().ref('customers').orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        console.log("Customer Key:"+snapshot.key); 
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `child_added` to keep a track of newly added records and to retrieve key.

```
firebase.database().ref('customers').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key); //This will print that unique key
});
```

Comment: I'm already retrieving the key after it is created. I need to check to see if the record exists and if it does, then pull back the key. If it doesn't exists then I create the new record. The email is what I am using to filter my customer object.

Comment: Thanks man! You got in the right direction. I was able to get it.

Comment: @user3183411 If this answer helped you, upvote it. If it solved your problem (which it seems to have done - the fact that you still needed your own query seems unrelated to the problem: you need to call `snapshot.key`), click the check mark to the left to accept it.